# Can anyone tell me how to use react bootstrap in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to use react-bootstrap in react and installed it by using command

```
npm install react-bootstrap --save
```

but it's not working, also tried to add external react-bootstrap.js but still getting  an error

```
error  'ReactBootstrap' is not defined  no-undef
 ✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

what am I doing wrong in this code. This is HTML file

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>React App</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"  />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.27.3/react-bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is JSX file.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';


class Hello extends Component{
render()
{
let { Button} = ReactBootstrap.Button;
    return(
    <div>
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="react-logo"/>
        <h1> Trying react</h1>
        <Button>Noob</Button> 
      </div>

    );
}
}
export default Hello;
```

and here the rendering code in other file.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(
 <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

the same code is working fine , If I remove

```
 let { Button} = ReactBootstrap.Button;
```

and

```
<Button>Noob</Button>
```

from JSX file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to import that component from react-bootstrap like - `var Alert = require('react-bootstrap').Alert;` 
For more information please take a look at this - https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started.html

Comment: Hi, @Rohan check this link https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/77 .
here someone mention that 
 `the react-bootstrap.js script adds a global var ReactBootstrap. You then have to create references to the individual components to use them with JSX` .

Comment: Add this at the top of your jsx file - `import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';`
and remove `let { Button} = ReactBootstrap.Button;`

Comment: hey, @ Rohan , I want to ask that .. every component I want to use , then  I have to import it. like
     `import  {Grid}  from  'react-bootstrap';`
     `import  {Row}  from  'react-bootstrap';`
     `import  {Col}  from  'react-bootstrap';`

 or Is there any better option??

Comment: yeah you will have to import it.